# Updating a particular array element in nedb

Tags: database, nedb

In nedb, I have an array field in a document.
How will I update an array element at any index?

For example,

```
{  
  fruits:['mango','apple','banana']
}
```

I would like to modify the 2nd element and make the array as `['mango','pear','banana']`.

How to do it using `db.update`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
db.update({_id:idToUpdate}, {
    $set:{'fruits[1]':'pear'}
}, {}, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot notation with index:

```
db.update({_id: id, {$set: {'fruits.1': 'pear'}}, {}, callback)
```

One thing though, you have to be sure that you using the right index.